# How to set Google Analytics to current month?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there no way to do this? For example, if you're in behavior > all pages and want to see the current month, you have to change the ending date to the current day every day.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to the right upper corner.

2) Click on 3 vertical circles next to your gmail icon

3) You should be in "Edit User Settings". Change default date range to 30 days.

4) Hit "Save User Settings"

You should now see 30 day stats under your GA account. Including behavior stats and whatnot.

It's not exactly "current month" settings, but last 30 days. If you want to see just April and today is April 10th, then you should select April days and always do it **manually**. Sorry, GA doesn't have that.

Comment: Why is this an answer? It's just stating what is already known from the question.

Comment: @4thSpace You asked if there's a way to do this, so answering that there isn't is a perfectly acceptable answer. The Google Analytics UI requires a specific date range, and what  "current month" would comprise is a bit unclear (e.g., does that mean 30 days from today, or the start of the month till today - which is not advisable to include...). Using their [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/), you would be able to create a custom dashboard.

Comment: @4thSpace there is no workaround. I provided the best solution for you. You can't just log in to GA and getting your dashboard showing only April dates even if it's just April 2 or April 15. GA isn't that flexible. I know you only want to see stats for 1 month but you need to do it manually or set it up for last 30 days. That's what I explained you above

Comment: It isnt' stats for 1 month. It's for the current month. Again, I don't see this as an answer. I'm already using the workaround (manually setting the ending date each day).